# Python/Seleium: Code to scrape field from webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I need some help. I am trying to scrape a section/field/div from a webpage. Please see attachment for the source code. The green arrow is the field I am trying to scrape.[Webpage source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4YRr.png)
[Selenium scrape code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV4vY.png)

**self.first_xpath = '//div[@class="boxQuoteOverviewHeader"]/div/div/div/div'**

When I run the code it does not scrape. What I am missing here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is the error what output do you get when running the script can you provide us with the whole code?

Comment: The program runs but it doesn't scrape. No output.

Comment: No errors present? Try using /iq-format-number with .text at the end.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide your code that you used to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to scrape this like any other element:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {paste your User Agent here}

page = requests.get('https://your-url.com', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find('iq-format-number', {'data-qt': 'lastTradePriceTrHrs'})
```

Output of `result.text` should be `'6.18'`
Try it out with your data and give feedback f it works for you.